# Can not get the actual data using Angular.js and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have an issue while uploading the data into server using Angular.js and PHP.I am explaining my code below.

```
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right oditek-form" style="width:180px">Latitude:</span>
 <div ng-class="{ 'myError': billdata.lati.$touched && billdata.lati.$invalid }">
<input type="text" name="lati" id="latitude" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="Add Latitude coordinate" ng-model="latitude"  ng-pattern="/^(\+|-)?[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$/" ng-keypress="clearField('businessno');" >
</div>
```

Here i need to load the latitude value lets say `+20.12345`.Check my controller part below.

```
supplierData= "latitude="+$scope.latitude;
$http({
        method:'POST',
        url:"php/customerInfo.php",
        data:supplierData,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
}).then(function successCallback(response){
      console.log('res 2nd',response.data);
},function errorCallback(response) {
})
```

My PHP code is given below.

```
$latitude=$_POST['latitude'];
echo $latitude;exit;
```

Here my problem is suppose user entered the value like this `+20.12345` and when i echo the same value at PHP side its coming like this `20.12345` where i did not get any + like character.Here i need is user entered the value like above it should come same in PHP side also.Please help me.

Comment: $longitude=$_POST['longitude'];
echo $latitude;exit; Don't you think your PHP code is wrong ? you are echoing $latitude and getting the value in $longitude

Comment: @UmairFarooq : Please check my updated post.

Comment: Cast it to a string.

Comment: No,I cast but same issue.